# Google ML Kit face detection can not identify faces from uri

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bitmap, face-detection, google-mlkit

I'm using google ml kit for face detection, then use bounding Box function to crop faces.
I successfully integrate cameras ,then want to add select from gallery function, which I successfully implement previous training app that I wrote in Java, yet I can find why App written in Kotlin can not identify image Uri from gallery.

I tried multiple methods InputImage.fromBirmap(), InputImage.fromFilePath() and InputImage.fromByteArray("use nv21"), and used Image View to display images with rotation degrees that seems perfect. You can find codes that initiated by on click method below, except InputImage.fromFilePath() and InputImage.fromByteArray("use nv21") which tried first, then delete the codes.
Also thank you before hand.

```
private fun selectImage() {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 11)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 11) {
                if (data != null){
                    val bitmap = getBitmapFromUri(data.data!!)
                    
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: ${data.data!!}")

                    val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(data.data!!)
                    val exif = ExifInterface(inputStream!!)
                    val rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL
                    )
                    val rotationInDegrees: Int = exifToDegrees(rotation)
                    inputStream.close()
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: rotation: $rotation")

                    if (bitmap != null) selectedImageAnalyser(bitmap, rotationInDegrees)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun exifToDegrees(exifOrientation: Int): Int {
        return when (exifOrientation) {
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> {
                90
            }
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> {
                180
            }
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> {
                270
            }
            else -> 0
        }
    }

    private fun getBitmapFromUri(uri: Uri): Bitmap? {
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
        try {
            bitmap = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
                val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(
                    contentResolver, uri
                )
                ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
            } else {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, uri)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return bitmap
    }

    private fun selectedImageAnalyser(bitmap: Bitmap, rotationDegree: Int) {
        val mBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
        val inputImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(mBitmap, rotationDegree)
        val rotation = inputImage.rotationDegrees
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: rotation: $rotation")

        binding!!.ivFace.apply {
            visibility = View.VISIBLE
            setImageBitmap(inputImage.bitmapInternal)
        }



        faceDetector.process(inputImage)
            .addOnSuccessListener { faces ->
                if (faces.isNullOrEmpty()){
                    val croppedFace = cropToBox(bitmap,faces[0].boundingBox,rotation)
                    startEnrollDialog(croppedFace)
                } else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "selectedImageAnalyser: face can not identified")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { Log.d(TAG, "selectedImageAnalyser: \n\t Cause: ${it.cause} \n\t Message: ${it.message}") }
            .addOnCompleteListener {  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by if block which looks like this "if (faces.isNullOrEmpty())". Do you catch the mistake, yes I forgot to add '!'.

Please accept my sincerest apologies for wasting your time.
Best Regards